# bootstrap simple dropdown not showing at all

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to put something like a side menu to my ASP.NET MVC5 application, but the dropdown-menu just doesn't show.

Resuming, I just copy the example from bootstrap page, pasted and nothing shows up:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```

Created this fiddle that have the issue: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/ctpaula/yx689kzn/1/)

Maybe the problem is something more that I have to add. I want something just like the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il4KG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you load `popper.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`. See below:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>    
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the order for your Javascript should be as follows;

1. jQuery
2. popper.js
3. bootstrap.js

Comment: I did that, but my problem was the answer of @Devtician.
Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the menu item a div with a class of "dropdown" and include the dropdown button as well.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
   <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the Bootstrap docs, if you want to read more about dropdowns: [Bootstrap 4 - Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#single-button)

Comment: @CristopherTabordadePaula Glad I could help! Please mark this answer as correct in that case as well.